# SQL Server  Text Datatype Maxlength = 65,535?

Tags: sql-server, text, types

Software I'm working with uses a text field to store XML. From my searches online, the text datatype is supposed to hold 2^31 - 1 characters. Currently SQL Server is truncating the XML at 65,535 characters every time. I know this is caused by SQL Server, because if I add a 65,536th character to the column directly in Management Studio, it states that it will not update because characters will be truncated.

Is the max length really 65,535 or could this be because the database was designed in an earlier version of SQL Server (2000) and it's using the legacy `text` datatype instead of 2005's?

If this is the case, will altering the datatype to `Text` in SQL Server 2005 fix this issue?

Comment: It's part of a mirrored database in a synchronization process.  I was hoping to avoid having to modify the field on all of the clients too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

that is a limitation of SSMS not of the text field, but you should use varchar(max) since text is deprecated

[image]

Here is also a quick test

```
create table TestLen (bla text)

insert TestLen values (replicate(convert(varchar(max),'a'), 100000))

select datalength(bla)
from TestLen
```

Returns 100000 for me

Comment: You saved me from having to rebuild a front-end system! I was seeing this 65535 limit when viewing some imported data from a front-end, which meant I was going to have to limit file sizes to less than 65k characters lol. I can now see that it's just the SSMS results that were truncated and not the data, itself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little script I wrote for getting out all data

```
    SELECT @data = N'huge data';

    DECLARE @readSentence NVARCHAR (MAX) = N'';


    DECLARE @dataLength INT = ( SELECT LEN (@data));


    DECLARE @currIndex INT = 0;

    WHILE @data <> @readSentence
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @temp NVARCHAR (MAX) = N'';


            SET @temp = ( SELECT SUBSTRING (@data, @currIndex, 65535));


            SELECT @temp;

            SET @readSentence += @temp;


            SET @currIndex += 65535;


        END;
```

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL 2000 should allow up to 2^31 - 1 characters (non unicode) in a text field, which is over 2 billion. Don't know what's causing this limitation but you might wanna try using varchar(max) or nvarchar(max). These store as many characters but allow also the regular string T-SQL functions (like LEN, SUBSTRING, REPLACE, RTRIM,...).

Comment: In fact nvarchar only stores half the number of characters than varchar because it is unicode and uses 2 bytes per character.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to convert the column, you might as well, since the `text` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx).

The recommendation is to use `varchar(MAX)` or `nvarchar(MAX)`. In your case, you could also use the `XML` data type, but that may tie you to certain database engines (if that's a consideration).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at

- [XML Support in Microsoft SQL Server
  2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx)
- [Beginning SQL Server 2005 XML
  Programming](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/beginning-sql-server-2005-xml-programming/)

So I would rather try to use the data type appropriate for the use. *Not make a datatype fit your use from a previous version.*