# SQL does not read more than 65536 characters from a text column

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a text field in a table with other spatial types. As part of a SSIS package, I am using this text field to run an update (as a SQL task) on the same table and update the geometry and geography columns. I was able to successfully run the following query yesterday

```
UPDATE Location 
SET [Geometry] = geometry::STGeomFromText(ShapeText, 4326).MakeValid()
FROM Location 
WHERE ShapeText IS NOT NULL
```

But, today it has been throwing the following exception:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 A .NET Framework error occurred
>   during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
>   System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 65536
>   of the input.

When I looked at the shape, its definitely a valid shape. So the problem is not in the shape but that SQL is only reading upto 65536 characters from the column. And it works when the shapetext is less than 65536 characters.

It would be great if someone coud help me with this and let me know how to read more than 65536 characters from a text field.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008267/ms-sql-server-text-datatype-maxlength-65-535

Comment: @RayToal: Thanks, but I still see the same exception

Comment: No way to store the shape text as a varchar or nvarchar?  Is it actually of type text?

Comment: It is a type of text and I quickly changed it to a varchar(max) to test it and ran the query again and still the same exception.

Comment: I have worked with varchar(max) values that exceed 64k.  SQL Server does not have a problem with them, per se.  I suspect the issue is the interactino between StGeomFromText and MakeValid.

Comment: I'll try again with varchar(Max) and post my finds later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally I found the problem and the solution for it.Even though the problem seems a bit too discrete, I hope it helps someone else.

PROBLEM: I started searching for this 65536 character error message and it led me to blogs that mentioned the SQL memory issues. I then checked my SQL logs and it did have error messages reporting:

> Failed to reserve contiguous memory of Size= 65536

The confusion was that it was working one day and then the next day, it started throwing me the error messages, so I definitely had a memory eating operation somewhere. On careful examination, I found that there was a derived column on my SSIS package that was the root of all memory issues. The derived column was checking the length of a text field and setting it to null if the length was zero.

SOLUTION: I removed the derived column operation and replaced it with a SQL task instead and its working beautifully once again.