# string getting truncated when saved into database

Tags: c#, .net, database

I have a database datatype defined as Text:

> text columns are variable-length columns that can hold up to 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup> - 1) bytes of printable characters.

What does that means exactly? How many string characters will I be able to save into the Text column?

Basically, I try to save a c# string object into that column where

```
myString.ToString().Length == 39418
```

but when I pull it back from the database

```
myString.ToString().Length == 32768
```

-----------EDITED---------------

guys this is very confusing.

The Text column is defined as 2,147,483,647 bytes which is 2GB

The string i'm trying to save is ?System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(param.Value.ToString()) 78836 bytes i.e. 0.0000734217 gigabytes

So that confirms that what I am trying to save IS NOT too big for the Text datatype column? i.e. I'm saving 0.0000734217 GB into a column capable of handling 2GB

I'm using Sybase. Saving like this:

```
        OdbcParameter param = new OdbcParameter();
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        param.Size = int.MaxValue;
        param.Value = myBigString
        parameters.Add(param);
        OdbcHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, sql, parameters);
```

And retreiving like this

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    OdbcDataAdapter adp = new OdbcDataAdapter(command, conn);
    conn.Open();
    adp.Fill(ds);....
```

Also when I try this I can still see the data is truncated so it doesn't look like a problem when retreiving the data

```
var obj = OdbcHelper.ExecuteScalar(connectionString, "select myBigString FROM ...");
```

Comment: How are you pulling it back from the database?

Comment: If this is SQL Server, don't use `text` as the data type, it is deprecated.

Comment: How exactly are you saving this to the database?  If you have C# code involved I'd assume you're using either ADO or an ORM...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008267/sql-server-text-datatype-maxlength-65-535

Comment: You're either truncating on insert (probably unlikely) or when reading back (most likely) into a buffer. Post the code that gets myString.

Comment: Post code where in insert the sting.

Comment: I still don't see the part where you explicitly read the string out of your dataset.

Comment: Hi jszigeti. When I call ExecuteScalar (editied in the question) and retreive the data I can still see it's truncated

Comment: In SQL do a select len(col) do see if it is truncated on the way in or out.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, do not use `TEXT` as it is deprecated.  Use `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` for Unicode data.  This will allow you to store up to 2GB of data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

> Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and
>   can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum
>   storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is
>   two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO
>   synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character
>   varying.

2,147,483,647 bytes is approximately 1.862GB and the maximum capacity for that column. I assume the data you're attempting to store is too large for the column, hence the data being truncated.

Comment: thanks. Let's assume for a sec that I cannot change the datatype of the database. So am i bascially saving too large a string into the column? What does 2,147,483,647 bytes mean? Can the Text column not handle a string of lenght 39418? I need to know this specific question please

Comment: @Bob - 2,147,483,647 bytes is approximately 1.862GB.  I assume the data you're attempting to store is too large for the column, hence the data being truncated.

Comment: Unicode in "worst case" uses four bytes per character (iirc). `39418 * 4 << 2147483647` so I think you should be safe there. Doesn't explain why you would lose characters though.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can find out how big a string of 39418 charachers is so I can confirm this?

Comment: Btw. [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187993.aspx) (which you shouldn't use. Use [nvarchar(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186939.aspx) instead) is non-Unicode, so you should have the full 2147483647 characters. Even if the server code page uses double-byte characters.

Comment: GetByteCount(myBigString) returns 78836 bytes which is 0.0000734217 gigabytes... so what i'm saving isn't too big for the Text datatype

Answer (score 0):

use the **nvarchar(MAX)** type for that column

[image: real example from a DB in action]

Comment: a usefull related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax

Comment: Thanks meorfi, just trying to confirm if it's because of the datatype of the column first. Question edited to reflect this

Comment: @Bob, can you check the string which you pass by param.Value with a profiler. Has it full value before gets written in DB, or, may the trunc is when it pass from System to DB.

Answer (score 0):

In my connection string I needed to add textsize=2147483647