# Can I change the the Datatype of Column Body of table BlogPost in Nopcommerce Database?

Tags: entity-framework-4, nopcommerce

I want to post my blog in my store which is of Nopcommerce and the size of my blog contents is greater than 4000 characters.

Now I want to change that limit but it does not allow me change the datatype or the size of current datatype which is string.

I have tried to change it from BlogPostMap file, but it does not work for me.

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to blog post sizes, nor in the database nor in the code. The database definition for body is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and you don't need to modify the BlogPostMap file.

The problem is somewhere else. Are you using the nopCommerce interface or creating blogs using a custom process?

Maybe a problem with Management Studio? Check this:
[SQL Server  Text Datatype Maxlength = 65,535?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008267/sql-server-text-datatype-maxlength-65-535)