# Doctrine auto limit the length of my text field to 64512 chars

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have a field in a table of type "text" which usually contain pictures in "base64"; When the images are large, they condifican approximately 200,000 characters. The "text" of the base allows me to store up to 4 million characters. But Doctrine cuts my character string in 64512.

Versions:

- Doctrine 2.4.4 on Symfony 2.5.3
- DB: Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2039 (Intel X86) 
  May  3 2005 23:18:38 
  Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

---

Declaration of the field.

```
 /**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mensaje", type="text")
 */
 private $mensaje;
```

Getter method:

```
 public function get($value){
    return mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_detect_order(), true) === 'UTF-8' ?
    $value : mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8');    
 }
 /**
  * Get mensaje
  *
  * @return text
  */
  public function getMensaje()  {
    return $this->get($this->mensaje);
  }
```

I've tried:

- Limiting the size of the text with "length"
- Using other data types such as "clob" or "longtext"
- Add data to the end of the string to verify that there is a problem of php (no problem with that)

Tnks.

Comment: Are you sure Doctrine is the issue here? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008267/sql-server-text-datatype-maxlength-65-535

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but yes, Doctrine is the problem, the database I have the entire string, which is why I know that the size is 200 thousand characters.
http://s23.postimg.org/lqe3mciwr/basedatos.png

Comment: When is the truncation happening? On insertion or after hydration?

Comment: how to get more than 64512 length string

Answer (score 1):

You can use longtext you can store a text with a length up to 4294967292

```
    TINYTEXT   : 2 ^  8 - 1 = 255 
    TEXT       : 2 ^ 16 - 2 = 65534 
    MEDIUMTEXT : 2 ^ 24 - 3 = 16777213 
    LONGTEXT   : 2 ^ 32 - 4 = 4294967292
```

To do so you need to add columnDefinition="longtext" to your field

Comment: Thanks, but when i change the DataType showme this error: 
http://s15.postimg.org/mwtcm4jaz/error.png

Comment: I think you need to do somethink like this : @ORM\Column(name="mensaje", type="text" , columnDefinition="longtext")

Comment: Thank you, but the way you're declaring the field, as we currently have it

Comment: I have added columnDefinition="longtext" to force column type un mysql

Comment: `longtext` doesn't exist on SQL Server. Have you checked your table column definition is an `VARCHAR(MAX)`? That is what Doctrine should use for SQL Server for a text field.

Answer (score 0):

In my project we use a base64 image (not as large as yours though) and we use a doctrine decimal type.
    @ORM\Column(name="image", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=4, nullable=true)

We use sql server 2012 though with a varchar(MAX) data type.

When the image is uploaded we base64_encode($imageFile) and persist that...

```
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if(null === $this->imageFile){
        return;
        }

        $data = file_get_contents($this->imagefile);
        $base64 = base64_encode($data);

        $this->image = $base64;
    }

    public function getImage()  {
    return $this->get($this->Image);
}
```

The getImage then returns a base64 encoded string that we use to display. Works on a string length 129400 for me. No converting from DB.

Comment: Thanks, but I keep a field full html, with tags including some images in base64, I have no control over it, because it is an html generated by a plugin

Answer (score 0):

PHP truncate all my strings with a several characters. The solution was in the php.ini

```
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647
; Valid range 0 - 2147483647. Default = 4096.
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```

by default was set into 4096, and there be the problem.
Thanks for the time!!!